# How can I solve this system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Really hard problem!!

$$
\begin{align}
  xy&=-2 \\
 xy^{a-1} &=-512 \\
 x(y^a-1 ) &= 341y-341
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Plugging the 1st and 2nd equations into the 3rd, we get a quadratic equation for y.

Comment: Did you want the third equation to be $x(y^a-1)=-341y-341$? The solution is much nicer then.

Answer (score 6):

From the first two (divide them) you get $y^{a-2}=256$.

So the third becomes $xy\cdot y \cdot 256 -x=341y-341$.

$-512 y-x=341y-341$. Plug $x=-2/y$ in this last equation you get a quadratic equation.

It is not really that hard problem. You just have to play a bit with it.